# Why ContactManager.BeginSearch return zero result for some strings even if strings present as contact

Tags: c#, wpf, lync, skype-for-business

I am searching string to find contact details using Lync SDK but for some of strings are returning zero search result even if I have contact same as string.

```
ContactManager contact_manager = LyncClient.GetClient().ContactManager;
contact_manager.BeginSearch(name, SearchProviders.Default, SearchFields.AllFields, SearchOptions.Default, 50, SearchCallback, new object[] { name, SearchProviders.Default });
```

In above code I am getting ContactManager even I am able to search some of string.

**What can be the reason of not getting result for all string?**

Note: Whatever string I am searching that is present as Lync contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs for [SearchProviders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.searchproviders_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx) believe it or not `SearchProviders.Default` is actually deprecated. If you want to mimic the behaviour of the Lync client use `SearchProviders.Reserved1` (if you check `Microsoft.Office.Uc.SearchProviders` this maps to `ucSearchProviderLync`). I have found that in certain AD/Exchange setups this provider does not always work. So at least have a fall back to `SearchProviders.Default` if `SearchProviders.Reserved1` fails.

Comment: Late acceptance, but this answer was solved my problem and later I contacted Microsoft for official resolution and problem was in Lync server from Microsoft side. So after server side fix I change `SearchProviders` back to `Default` and every thing is working fine as of now. Thanks.